# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'model') at Proxy.$_setUpEditorEvents

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, ckeditor5, inertiajs, laravel-mix-vue3

I am trying to use CKEditor 5 with my Inertia Application in Laravel. But after following the documentation I am getting below error.

[image]

**index.vue** file

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <ckeditor :editor="editor" v-model="editorData" :config="editorConfig"></ckeditor>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue';
    import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';

    export default {
        name: 'app',
        components: {
            ckeditor: CKEditor.component
        },
        data() {
            return {
                editor: ClassicEditor,
                editorData: '<p>Content of the editor.</p>',
                editorConfig: {
                    // The configuration of the editor.
                }
            };
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try vue@3.2.30 if you using Vue 3

Comment: I notice that 3.2.31 breaks this, but why?

Comment: doesn't work in 3.2.30 now, any permanent solution