# I got error Cannot read properties of undefined installing ckeditor5 into Inertiajs 3/vuejs 3 app

Tags: laravel, ckeditor, vuejs3, inertiajs

In laravel 9/Inertiajs 3/vuejs 3 app I add ckeditor5 (with Composition API)
reading https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/getting-started/frameworks/vuejs-v3.html with code :

```
   <ckeditor
       :editor="editor"
        v-model="editorData"
       :config="editorConfig"
   ></ckeditor>


   ...
        let editorData = ref(' editorData init text')
        let editor = ref(ClassicEditor)
        let editorConfig = ref({})
```

I have error :

ckeditor.js?fbec:5 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'model')
at Proxy.$_setUpEditorEvents (ckeditor.js?fbec:5:4617)
at eval (ckeditor.js?fbec:5:4054)

Searching in net I found branch : [TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'model') at Proxy.$_setUpEditorEvents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71175717/typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-model-at-proxy-setu)

I upgrated vuejs to the latest version :

```
$ npm -v
6.14.15
$ node -v
v14.18.3
```

npm list vue
/ProjectPath/
├── vue@3.2.31
└─┬ vue3-colorpicker@2.0.4
└─┬ vue3-normal-library@0.1.6
└── vue@3.2.31  deduped

What I see in debugging vue :
https://prnt.sc/vrlktjNrlNIM
but I still have the same error

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find a fix to this issue?

Comment: No I did not find

Comment: I had the same issue and upgrade the ckeditor Version and it all of a sudden worked.